# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in W:\domains\bahilistich\news.php on line 53

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Помоги, пожалуйста, разобраться, как разрешить следующее предупреждение:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in W:\domains\bahilistich\news.php on line 53

```
<?php
    $host="localhost";
    $user="zettrap";
    $pass="199907zetTrap";
    $db_name="my_bd_zaytsev";
    $link=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);
   mysqli_select_db($link,$db_name);
    $sql = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM 'news'"); 
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) 
{ 
echo "Автор: ".$result['autor']." <br>"; 
echo "Название: ".$result['subject']." <br>";  
echo "Дата: ".$result['data']." <br>"; 
echo "<img src =".$result['foto'].">"."</img><br><br>"; 
        
    }
?>
```

Comment: И в чём вопрос?

Comment: @dIm0n, ошибка в шапке.

Comment: Разве это ошибка? Почитайте [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот Warning очень просто решается. Нужно просто повнимательней к коду своему приглядеться

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "zettrap";
$pass = "199907zetTrap";
$db_name = "my_bd_zaytsev";

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `news`");

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "Автор: " . $result['autor'] . " <br>";
    echo "Название: " . $result['subject'] . " <br>";
    echo "Дата: " . $result['data'] . " <br>";
    echo "<img src =" . $result['foto'] . ">" . "</img><br><br>";
}
```